# Why will this pattern hold

Tags: solution-verification, permutations, combinations

I have the question "the number of elements in the set $\{n\in\mathbb{N}:10\le n\le 100\text{ and }(3^n -3) is \text{ a multiple of }7\}$

is ________".

To solve this my book computed $3^1 - 3$, $3^2 - 3$,
$3^3 - 3$, ... , $3^7 - 3$.Then stated that from these numbers only $3^1 - 3$ and $3^7 - 3$ is divisible by 7.Then it said that similarly the values of n will be 1,7, 13, 20, ..., 97.Thus the number of elements of n is 15.I am unable to understand how my book without proving the pattern stated that all the values of n will follow the pattern

Comment: There once lived a man by the name of Pierre de Fermat, that's why.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @IvanNeretin

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: @IvanNeretin thank you for helping people like me who didn't even know the name of Mr. Fermat

Comment: @IvanNeretin I found that Fermat's little theorem states that if p is a prime number, then for any integer a, the number a^(p) − a is an integer multiple of p.But in my case the division is not always with p.

Comment: Example, according to my book (3^(6) -3)/7 will give me an integer.But the Fermat's little theorem does not cover this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try computing the first 6 powers of $3$, modulo $7$:

$3^{1} \equiv 3 (\text{mod } 7)$

$3^{2} \equiv 2 (\text{mod } 7)$

$3^{3} \equiv 6 (\text{mod } 7)$

$3^{4} \equiv 4 (\text{mod } 7)$

$3^{5} \equiv 5 (\text{mod } 7)$

$3^{6} \equiv 1 (\text{mod } 7)$

Notice how it will now cycle, since $3^{7} \equiv 3 (\text{mod } 7)$. So now, we can say that, in general, if $n=6k+q$, then $3^{n} \equiv 3^{q} (\text{mod } 7)$.

So, since we want $3^{n} - 3 \equiv 0 (\text{mod } 7)$, we get

$3^{n} \equiv 3 (\text{mod } 7) \implies n=6k+1$.

So, out answer is any values of $n$ that can be written as $6k+1$. In our interval, this is $13,19,25,\dots,97$, as desired

Comment: But how are you so sure that this cyclic pattern will be true? (I am asking because you have not gave any proof for it)

Comment: Yes i have. Multiplying on both sides of an congruence relation is a valid operation, meaning after we get. $3^{6}\equiv 1$ , its clear that $3^{7} \equiv 3$, which in turn means $3^{8} \equiv 3^{2}$ and so on. If you *really* want to, you can easily peform induction, but its obvious from just multiplying on both sides

Comment: Thanks, a lot! I didn't know this was the case ( I basically searched online everywhere for this step, so when I say thank you, I really mean thank you)